# Set login shell if /etc/shells is missing

Tags: shell, login

On a server which thousands of users loginto the admins seem to have neglected some basics. My default shell is csh I would like to use bash, but `chsh` errors because /etc/shells does not exist. To make things worse my second thought was usermod, which is unavailable on the machine.

The obvious solution is to create /etc/shells but I am not an admin and they seem to be unresponsive to such matters.

Is there a way to set my default shell other than using chsh or usermod? If not is there something better than running `/usr/bin/bash -l` every time I log in?

Comment: Did you try adding `/usr/bin/bash -l` to your `~/.csh_profile`?

Comment: No, unless you convince/bribe a sysamdin to change your user entry.

Answer (score 3):

Make csh transfer control to bash when you log in. Put this in your `.login`:

```
if ($?prompt == 0) then
  : # non-interactive shell, be conservative
else if (-x /usr/bin/bash) then
  exec /usr/bin/bash --login
fi
```